# Security problem when connecting to SQL from Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, security, windows-7

I need to connect to a SQL Server 2005 from a Windows 7 machine that is not joined to the domain. This has always worked on XP but on Win7 I get the following error (when connecting via TCP/IP):

> Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

The eventlog on the server has the errors:

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. [CLIENT: (myip)]
>
> Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: (myip)]

The error stays the same if I use the short or FQ server name. I also entered a Windows Credential for the server (since I am not connected to the domain). The connection to the server is OK (I can access network shares).

I spent a few hours trying to solve this but so far I have only found two workarounds:

- "runas.exe /netonly /user:user@company.dom QueryExpress.exe" This will allow me to connect with the correct user using TCP/IP.
- or using Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP.

Both options are not ideal (also not all servers have Named Pipes enabled).

Is it possible to get the authentication to work using TCP/IP without runas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either have to add the computername/logonid to SQL server or change it from Windows Authentication Mode to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't help as it would be impossible to administer for all clients/servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have the perks of Integrated Authentication without being on a domain - either create/join a domain or use SQL Authentication.